# Webpack configuration to concatenate JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, development-environment, webpack-4

Im using webpack 4 to bundle my dependencies (in this case AngularJS) like so:

**index.js**

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
// ...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  mode: "development",
  entry: "./build/index.js",
  output: {
      path: __dirname + '/public/js',
      filename: "bundle.js"
  }
}
```

This generates a `bundle.js` file containing all my dependencies.

I would additionally like to use it as a task runner to concatenate the Angular JS files from `/build/js` into a single file (lets call it `app.js`) thats placed into `/public/js`

Ideally, I would like the representation of the concatenated angular files (what would be in `app.js`) to be included within `bundle.js` along with my dependencies - though Im not sure if this is possible or best-practice.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/multiple-entry-points ?

Comment: this was helpful, thank you! is there a way to select all files in a given directory as an entry point `entry: { a: [ "./build/index.js", "./build/app/js/*" ] }`

Comment: Would you not just point it at a file that required all the files you want - for example we have a components folder and we point the entry at an index.js which then requires all the files in that directory (but not sure if that's what you're meant to do as I'm quite new to webpack myself!)

Comment: yes, thats definitely an option but index.js would need to be updated everytime a new file is added or removed. I was hoping for a more hand-off solution where I can add/remove files and have webpack deal with it

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of a pain! I'll see if someone comes up with something else as I would also like to see if there is a better option :)

Comment: ok thank you again!

Comment: What you want is to use webpack like grunt or gulp which is not right. Whenever you add new js file related to some component, you `require` or `import` that file to you component or module or index.js file whichever closer. and that file will be processed by webpack. You dont need to add it into index.js always.

Comment: thank you, Ashish. you are correct that I want to use it like grunt/gulp - why is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pete has pointed out in the comment, webpack input accepts an array of entry paths. Webpack itself doesn't take glob pattern, but you can use the `glob` package to do so (if you use webpack, it's likely that you've already installed it, otherwise [get it here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)):

```
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: glob.sync('./src/**/*.js'), // ['./src/a.js', './src/dir/b.js']

  ...
}
```

Hope it helps!